Flux of $\mathbf{F}=(z+\sin(y), xyz, 1)$ across the boundary of $V=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: 0\leq z\leq x^2+y^2\leq 2\}$
I have calculated the outward flux of $\mathbf{F}=(z+\sin(y), xyz, 1)$ across  $V=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3: 0\leq z\leq x^2+y^2\leq 2\}$ directly and using the divergence theorem and the answers I have got seem to coincide but I am still unsure if I have done the calculations with the right orientation: I should calculate the outward flux but it seems to me that $\frac{\partial\mathbf{g}}{\partial r}\times\frac{\partial\mathbf{g}}{\partial\theta}$ is pointing inside $V$ which is a contradiction; so, I would be grateful if someone would check out my work and explain to me how to verify that I have chosen the right orientation. Thanks.
What I have done:
Given that $\partial V=\partial V_{top}\cup\partial V_{lat}+\partial V_{bottom}$ we parametrize the top surface boundary of $V$ by $\mathbf{g}:(0,\sqrt{2})\times (0,2\pi)\to\mathbb{R}^3,\ \mathbf{g}\begin{pmatrix}r\\ \theta\end{pmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}r\cos(\theta)\\ r\sin(\theta)\\ r^2\end{bmatrix}$ so $\frac{\partial\mathbf{g}}{\partial r}=(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta), 2r)$,  $\frac{\partial\mathbf{g}}{\partial\theta}=(-r\sin(\theta),r\cos(\theta), 0)$, $\frac{\partial\mathbf{g}}{\partial r}\times\frac{\partial\mathbf{g}}{\partial\theta}=(-2r^2\cos(\theta), -2r^2\sin(\theta), r)$, the lateral surface boundary by $\mathbf{h}:[0,2\pi]\times [0,2]\to\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbf{h}\begin{pmatrix}\theta\\ z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\cos(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)\\ z\end{bmatrix}$, $\frac{\partial\mathbf{h}}{\partial\theta}=(-\sin(\theta),\cos(\theta),0), \frac{\partial\mathbf{h}}{\partial z}=(0,0,1), \frac{\partial\mathbf{h}}{\partial\theta}\times \frac{\partial\mathbf{h}}{\partial z}=(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta),0)$, the bottom surface by $\mathbf{f}:(0,2\pi)\times(0,\sqrt{2})\to\mathbb{R}^3,\ \mathbf{f}\begin{pmatrix}\theta\\ r\end{pmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}r\cos(\theta)\\ r\sin(\theta)\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ so $\frac{\partial\mathbf{f}}{\partial r}=(\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta), 0)$,  $\frac{\partial\mathbf{f}}{\partial\theta}=(-r\sin(\theta),r\cos(\theta), 0)$, $\frac{\partial\mathbf{f}}{\partial\theta}\times\frac{\partial\mathbf{f}}{\partial r}=(0, 0, -r)$
we get
\begin{align}
\text{flux}_{\partial V}(\mathbf{F})&=\text{flux}_{\partial V_{top}}(\mathbf{F})+\text{flux}_{\partial V_{lat}}(\mathbf{F})+\text{flux}_{\partial V_{bottom}}(\mathbf{F})\\ &=\int_{\partial V_{top}}\mathbf{F}\left(\mathbf{g}(r,\theta)\right)\cdot\left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{g}}{\partial r}\times\frac{\partial\mathbf{g}}{\partial\theta}\right)drd\theta+\int_{\partial V_{lat}}\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{h}(\theta, z))\cdot\left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{h}}{\partial\theta}\times\frac{\partial\mathbf{h}}{\partial z}\right)d\theta dz\\ &+\int_{\partial V_{bottom}}\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{f}(\theta, r))\cdot\left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{f}}{\partial\theta}\times\frac{\partial\mathbf{f}}{\partial r}\right)d\theta dr=\\&=\int_{r=0}^{r=\sqrt{2}}\left(\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi}\left( (r^2+\sin(r\sin(\theta)))(-2r^2\cos(\theta))+r^4\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)(-2r^2\sin(\theta))+1\cdot r \right)dr\right)d\theta\\& +\int_{z=0}^{z=2}\left(\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi}(z+\sin(\sin(\theta))\cos(\theta)+(\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)z)\sin(\theta)+1\cdot 0)d\theta\right)dz\\& +\int_{r=0}^{r=\sqrt{2}}\left(\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi}[(0+\sin(r\sin(\theta)))0+0\cdot 0+1\cdot (-r)]d\theta\right)dr\\&=\int_{r=0}^{r=\sqrt{2}} \left(\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi}(-2r^4\cos(\theta)-2r^2\cos(\theta)\sin(2\sin(\theta))-2r^6\cos(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)+r)dr\right)d\theta+0-2\pi\\ &=\int_{r=0}^{r=\sqrt{2}}(2\pi r)dr-2\pi=2\pi-2\pi=0.
\end{align}
Applying the divergence theorem we get:
$$\text{flux}_{\partial V}(\mathbf{F})=
\iiint_V \text{div}(\mathbf{F})\,dxdydz=\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta=2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{r=\sqrt{2}}\int_{z=0}^{z=2}r\cos(\theta)r^2\cdot rdr d\theta=0.$$

I think you forgot part of the boundary. Also having the vector point inwards is not necessarily a contradiction. Due to the anti-symmetry of the cross product, there is a certain ambiguity in the normal vector, but i wouldn't worry about it too much.

@JosefK. Thanks. I have amended my calculation; is it correct now?

I haven't explicitly checked all the calculations in the integrals, but the bounds of the integrals and the parametrizations you have for the boundary look correct to me. Also, as a general rule if you are worried about the sign of the normal vector, in most calculus books I've seen, the "vector" $d \mathbf{S}$ is defined with a $\pm$ to make the normal vector point in the desired direction (that is $d \mathbf{S} = \pm \mathbf{n} dS$). There are more formal definitions to make this rigorous, but I wouldn't worry about it too much in cases like this. Your work looks nice!
